# How to split the csv column separated by delimeter using custom spliter?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, opencsv

I have a rest controller which has a post mapping which is supposed to accept csv/text as an input. Below is the format of the csv :-

```
id, name, phoneNumber
n1,Joe/Dowwel,123-212-3233
n2,Sara/Ali,132,232,3111
```

I am using open csv annotation which is as below to convert the csv to java pojo as an input to the post mapping controller method.:-

```
@CsvBindByPosition(position=2)
private String name;
```

This annotation will map the csv input field 'name' to the java object (POJO) field 'name' ( as shown below )

```
public class Employee {


    @CsvBindByPosition(position=1)
    private String id;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position=2)
    private String name;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position=3)
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Employee () {
    }
```

However the value of 'name' in the java pojo after the spring converter converts it will be ex : Joe/Dowwel ( With a delimeter '/' )

My requirement is to have 2 separate fields 'firstName' and 'lastName' in the Employee POJO such that I can split and separate it like 'firstName' = Joe and 'lastname'=Dowwel.

Is there any way that I can achieve it using a cleaner approach . Maybe using some more annotation to filter?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your input data does not map to your class structure. [Square peg, round hole.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole) No magic solution here.

You must either:

- Fix the data source, asking the publisher of the data to separate the single field of `name` into a pair of fields `given_name` & `surname`.
- Parse the data on your end, separating the single value into a pair of values.

The first option is ideal. Rather than hacking data after the fact, get the data communicated properly in the first place.

If that is not possible, you must find a workaround.

The first workaround that comes to mind for me is that you have a constructor on the `Employee` class that takes the incoming combined-name and splits it into two other fields. See `String::split`.

However, using that workaround with your current code means defining a redundant `name` member field on your `Employee` in addition to your first and last names member fields. So another workaround is not use the binding feature of your CSV library. Instead, write a bit of code that reads each field of CSV and passes it the constructor of `Employee`. When encountering the `name` field, split it, then pass both parts onto your constructor.